# Map and Groupby in one go

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors, collect

I have a model class as follows:

```
public class CCP implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "p_id")
    private Integer pId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "c_id")
    private Integer cId;

    @Column(name = "priority")
    private Integer priority;

}
```

I have the following requirement:

1. Convert the `List<CCP>` into `Map<pid, List<cid>>`

that is, i want to convert the list of CCP objects into a map having pid as key and a list of associated cids as values.

I tried the following things:

```
Map<Integer, List<CCP>> xxx = ccplist.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ccp -> ccp.getPId()));
```

But this gives the list of CCP only.

How can i get List of cid here instead of CCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mapping`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> xxx = 
    ccplist.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CCP::getPId,
                                          Collectors.mapping(CCP::getCId,
                                                             Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 ccplist.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               CCP::getPId,
               Collectors.mapping(CCP::getCId, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Eran got there 47 seconds before you with an identical solution, you so I gave him the upvote instead (even though I prefer your indentation style).